# Error 404 when I've added `$link = str_replace('index.php?route=', '', $link);` in seo_url.php in OpenCart

Tags: php, url, content-management-system, localhost, opencart

I'm removing `index.php?route=common/home` on the OpenCart URL's. I'm using the latest version of it. I've tried:

```
$link = str_replace('index.php?route=', '', $link);
```

But it directed me to the page:

> "Object not found......Error 404".

Comment: What is $link before the str_replace. What is it after and what do you want it to be?

Comment: else {
   $link = str_replace('index.php?route=', '', $link);
   return $link;
  } @WizKid

Comment: What is the value of $link before and after and what do you want it to be?

Comment: For example, the default URL in opencart of Checkout became "www.abc.com/checkout/checkout" when i inserted the said code above. But instead of displaying the content of checkout, it displayed "THE PAGE YOU REQUESTED CANNOT BE FOUND!". @WizKid

Comment: That was not my question. What is the value before and after and what do you want it to be?

Comment: I want a short and clear URL for every page in opencart theme. @WizKid

Comment: It is much easier if you answer my question

Comment: I didn't ask what the code was. I asked what the value of $link is before str_replace and what it is after. And what you want it to be

Comment: The value of $link before is the URL of the prev page you've clicked and the value after is the present URL. @WizKid

Comment: So give me an example. When you are testing the code what is it before and after and what do you want it to be?

Comment: @WizKid If You'd knew OpenCart well, You'd know that the `$link` value **before** is e.g. `http://store.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=1` and after the replacing taking it's part the `$link` will be e.g. `http://store.com/product/product&product_id=1`.

Comment: @shadyyx: I'm trying to get Yanyan to debug his/her code. And even if I did know that I have no idea what he/she want $link to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what you want is a sef url for each default opencart functionality correct? if is this, you can use a plugin, from anung, on official opencart board. The idea is a huge if/elseif with all default routes on "catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php", before checking the request path, like this:

```
    } elseif ($this->request->get['_route_'] ==  'contato') { 
        $this->request->get['route'] =  'information/contact';
    } elseif ($this->request->get['_route_'] ==  'account') { 
        $this->request->get['route'] =  'account/account';
    } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
```

and then, before checking if ($key == 'path'), you check you routes:

```
    } elseif (isset($data['route']) && $data['route'] ==   'information/contact') { 
        $url .=  '/contato';
    } elseif (isset($data['route']) && $data['route'] ==   'account/account') { 
        $url .=  '/account'; 
    } elseif ($key == 'path') {
```

if you want the plugin, you can search it on official opencart board.

Answer (score 0):

The problem You are facing is with the `.htaccess` file and the rewrite rules defined there. Because the rule is rewriting the URL (when SEO URLs are turned on) like

> http://store.com/some-category/some-sub-category/some-product

into URL like

> http://store.com/index.php?_route_=some-category/some-sub-category/some-product

This is meant for SEO URLs. If You are trying to create Your own SEO URLs You'd need to also modify the rewrite rules, e.g. from

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

into

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

(didn't test this one)